# How to rotate button back to horizontal?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgaffinetransform

I'm making a circle with different buttons all over, spaced out at equal intervals.
Here's what it looks like : [image]

I want to make it so that the picture doesn't rotate. How do I achieve that ? Here's the code.

```
- (void)drawWheel
{
    // Drawing the Wheel view
    wheelView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 275, 275)];
    wheelView.center = self.view.center;
    wheelView.layer.cornerRadius = wheelView.frame.size.width / 2.0;
    wheelView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    //wheelView.layer.borderWidth = 0.5f;

    CGFloat angleSize = 2 * M_PI / self.buttons.count;

    for(int i = 0; i < self.buttons.count; i++)
    {
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, wheelView.frame.size.width / 2.0, 40)];
        label.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(1.0f, 0.5f);
        label.layer.position = CGPointMake(wheelView.bounds.size.width / 2.0, wheelView.bounds.size.height / 2.0);
        label.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angleSize * i);
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        UIButton *button = [self.buttons objectAtIndex:i];
        button.center = CGPointMake(label.center.x, label.center.y + 15);
        button.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(label.transform, 2 * (angleSize * i));
        [label addSubview:button];
        [wheelView addSubview:label];
    }

    [self.view addSubview:wheelView];
}
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going on here. Could you possibly add some colour to the backgrounds of your labels and buttons to show what you're doing. Red - label and green - button or something.

Comment: Also, what are you adding the button to the label? If you're not using a label as a label (i.e. putting text on it) then just use a UIView.

Comment: I'll use the `UILabel` later. I need that. `buttons` is a `NSArray` with the buttons.

Comment: Which picture should not rotate?

Comment: All of them should remain straight. Horizontal. Like the Apple one.

Comment: Then why do you need cgaffine transform?

Comment: I think he's putting the label across the centre of the circle and rotating it to make the button follow the circumference of the circle. Hence the transform. But I'm not sure without seeing background colours of views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this I think...

```
- (void)drawWheel
{
    // Drawing the Wheel view
    wheelView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 275, 275)];
    wheelView.center = self.view.center;
    wheelView.layer.cornerRadius = wheelView.frame.size.width / 2.0;
    wheelView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    //wheelView.layer.borderWidth = 0.5f;

    CGFloat angleSize = 2 * M_PI / self.buttons.count;

    for(int i = 0; i < self.buttons.count; i++)
    {
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, wheelView.frame.size.width / 2.0, 40)];
        label.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(1.0f, 0.5f);
        label.layer.position = CGPointMake(wheelView.bounds.size.width / 2.0, wheelView.bounds.size.height / 2.0);
        label.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angleSize * i);
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        UIButton *button = [self.buttons objectAtIndex:i];
        button.center = CGPointMake(label.center.x, label.center.y + 15);

        // change this line
        button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-angleSize * i);

        [label addSubview:button];
        [wheelView addSubview:label];
    }

    [self.view addSubview:wheelView];
}
```

Here I am just transforming the button in the other direction with the same angle.

i.e. if the label is rotated 35 degrees then the button is rotated -35 degrees. This will mean the button is rotated 0 degrees relative to the sup review of the label.

Comment: Yep. That's what I wanted. Great job. :D Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I didn't check it, but could you change following code

`button.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(label.transform, 2 * (angleSize * i));`

to

`button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-1 * angleSize * i);`

Here I am just rotating your button to opposite direction